# What is the source of the verse "Ajnanta-jnapanam sastram"?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, shloka

There is a popular Sanskrit phrase **Ajñāta-jñāpanam śāstram** which means scriptures are meant for something which cannot be known through empirical evidence. What is the source of this phrase?

Comment: Add Tags based on topics the Q is about. And, here it is about a verse and which talks about some traits of a scripture. So, Sloka and scripture are the main tags here. I-R is an action that u are doing (just like asking-question) and not a topic.